# nth child without duplication in css

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to style item 1 to 10 but rather than do

```
&.nth-child(1) { //style } 
&.nth-child(2) { //style } 
&.nth-child(3) { //style }
```

and so on..

any range selector in css ?

Comment: I think you're looking to "loop" through css? You can do that in `sass` or using another `css` pre-processor...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) with equation in `an+b` format(where replace `a` and `b` with an integer and `n` would be `0, 1, 2,....`).

```css
li:nth-child(-n+10) {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
</ol>
```

---

**UPDATE :** If you need elements within a range then use multiple [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selector.

```css
li:nth-child(n+5):nth-child(-n+10) {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

The below snippet applies css to range from 2 to 3. Tweak it to your requirement.

**Explanation:**

`nth-child(n+2)` starts selecting from 2nd element to forward.
`nth-child(-n+3)` starts selecting from 3rd element to backwards.

*Combining two results in range.*

```css
li:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+3){
background: #000;
color: #fff
}
```

```html
<li>1</li>
<li>1</li>
<li>1</li>
<li>1</li>
<li>1</li>
<li>1</li>
```